# How to manage and deploy separate customer instances of the same node app?

Tags: node.js, deployment, version-control, google-cloud-platform, nuxt.js

I'm working on a personal project and I'm getting ready to deploy into production. The unique thing about this is the fact that there may be multiple clients that want to use the app, and each client would need their own separate app instance with their own server (I'm currently using `now.sh` for hosting the app, built with Nuxt). I'm a bit confused as to how I would manage something like that if say, I needed to make a change to the code base and want all customer instances to get the same change. It would be easy with 2-3 instances, but what if there are 10-20, or 100-200? How would you organize the instances in such a way as to push changes to all of them without spending half a day to do it manually? I hope that makes sense, and please let me know if I can clarify anything. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Each client would need their own separate app instance with their own server

*[A metapoint for future reference – its utility is likely low as you have already implemented your application.]*

Speaking from experience supporting systems designed in this way, a development model which creates a requirement that each tenant has independent infrastructure will be expensive to maintain as you scale up.

Moreover, outside specific problem domains,<sup>1</sup> it is rarely necessary. Such approaches typically trade easier development effort (by avoiding problems associated with partitioning your data model for each tenant) with more expensive and complex operational overheads when deploying and maintaining the service in production. In particular, you suffer from the following interrelated issues:

- **Cost inefficiency**: each instance of your application requires resources to provide service. Duplicating these resources for each tenant will incur significant overhead in the direct costs of paying for the resources and the indirect costs in the operational overheads of shipping code and maintaining your fleet.

  A handful of shared machines are easier to reason about and manage than a machine for every tenant, especially if you are new to hosting a production service. Moreover, if you desire to benefit from Google's SLA, you must deploy each tenant instance according to its [robust design principles](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/robustsystems) – meaning adding redundancy through multi-zone deployments (more infrastructure cost) for each tenant's deployment.
- **Less resource pooling and elasticity**: public clouds work *really well* when you can pool resources (especially CPU, memory) and operate your application elastically by making scaling decisions in response to your global real-world demand, shared across all tenants. A per-tenant deployment model can still gain these benefits, but you fragment your scaling domain to operate on a per-tenant basis. Unless your tenants are large and have significant infrastructure, this is almost certainly going to cost you more. Each tenant's instance must be scaled individually and you will probably pay for a significant number of idle instances to be ticking over when tenants are not using your system. (Disclaimer: I don't know what your system does, so I'm just going on industry trends.)

<sup>1</sup><sub>Such problem domains include highly-regulated industries which require hard boundaries to enforce strict data isolation between tenants of the system; anything of a security nature or sold to security-conscious individuals (debatable); instances where legacy (on-premises) applications are moved from per-tenant on-prem metal to cloud deployments, without significant refactoring of its data or deployment model.</sub>

---

> It would be easy with 2-3 instances, but what if there are 10-20, or 100-200? How would you organize the instances in such a way as to push changes to all of them without spending half a day to do it manually?

You will need to make your model reproducible and ensure your processes are automated. Anything less will become unmanageable and inevitably lead to drift between deployments, making them special "snowflakes" and much harder to reason about over time.

There are a variety of tools and approaches which help here:

- **Configuration management**: tools like [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) or [Salt](https://www.saltstack.com/). The desired configuration of each instance is specified in a declarative manner in source code. Rather than executing commands manually (e.g. over SSH to each machine), you delegate to the specific tool to interpret the desired configuration and mutate the configuration of the remote instances to cause them to converge to the expressed state. If a machine dies, you can replace it easily by re-running the deployment playbooks against a clean instance.
- **Image foundries**: public clouds make it cheap to spin up new instances. Unlike physical machines, you can destroy the instances and recreate them on each deployment. This pushes steps higher in your build chain, perhaps before the machines need customizing for each tenant (avoiding duplication of effort) and replacing machines with known-good versions built from a clean image helps eliminate drift. Tools like [Packer](https://www.packer.io/), combined with a config management tool, help build common images which you can deploy using [managed instance groups](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/).
- **Infrastructure as code**: tools like [Terraform](http://www.terraform.io) do a similar job to configuration management tools for declarative definition of your *infrastructure* – specifying the instance groups and their configuration in code, rather than pointing and clicking in the cloud management console.

Key takeaway: these tools help you define a process, but in themselves they are not solutions. You need to decide what steps are required in the delivery pipeline to get code from commit to production and implement **that**. These tools will help but are not a panacea.

---

## Containers

If you require per-tenant deployments and it is too late to change the architecture of your application, you might consider containerizing your application and using a managed container platform like [Google Kubernetes Engine](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/) to deploy it. GKE would allow you to run a common infrastructure (a Kubernetes "cluster") for each tenant, so benefiting from economies of scale in the infrastructure, while hosting an independent set of containers for each tenant in the system.

In this model, your deployment pipeline would involve steps to build the container images from code (using your favorite CI system, or a managed service like Google [Cloud Builder](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/)) and implementing a process for shipping these images to production.

Comment: WOW. Incredible answer. This was so helpful. I personally don't think it's a good idea to create separate tenant instances, since the only difference(s) between each instance are the logo, the sales code (each client gets a sales code and their customers can submit a service application using that unique sales code), and the CC address for the confirmation email. I just don't know how to use the same app instance AND be able to differentiate who is submitting an application under which sales code. I hope that makes sense. It's difficult to explain. Anyways, this was a fantastic write-up!

Comment: @JeremyGranger Happy to help. I don't know the specific architecture of your application, but you should consider whether you can represent tenants in your data model: for example, you might add a `tenant` table to your database, and have per-tenant data related using a foreign key relationship. You identify which tenant is accessing the system using their login credentials or by issuing them with a per-tenant URL, e.g. tenant.example.com, and verifying only the tenant's users can login at this address. Your code then filters data to only show data to that tenant. There are other approaches.

Comment: Check out some documentation on [multitenancy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy). Microsoft has good documentation on [multi-tenant database design approaches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/saas-tenancy-app-design-patterns) (ignore mention of Azure SQL, as it is mostly generic). The routing behavior is something to implement in your code and web server to ensure you can identify the tenant for any particular request and serve the appropriate app with a restricted view on the data.

Comment: After reading your advice I sat down and came up with a viable solution, and it has to do specifically with what you said about having per-tenant data. I was able to grab the subdomain from the request (as I'm using Nuxt's excellent SSR capability) and retrieve cloud images, cc address, and sales code based on that. THANKS again for your help. I don't think I've ever received such a well-thought-out answer on any platform! I've learned some valuable things. I appreciate it!